# How to store a sqlite blob in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, blob

I have images that are recieved from a web service and converted to `UIImage`. I need to store them as `sqlite blob` in a database.

This is the database table:

[image]

I have tried to use `NSData` to store it as `blob`

Here's what I've tried:

```
let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
let data = image!.pngData()! as NSData
let recurso1 = Recurso(idRecurso: 1, recurso: "paisaje1", _extension: "png", contenido: data)

if !dataManager.insertRecurso(db, recurso: recurso1) {
    print("No se pudo registrar recurso")
}
```

The insert function:

```
let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)

func insertRecurso(_ db: OpaquePointer?, recurso: Recurso) -> Bool {
    var stmt: OpaquePointer? = nil;
    let sql = "INSERT INTO recurso(idRecurso, recurso, extension, contenido) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 0, Int32(recurso.idRecurso))
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, recurso.recurso, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, recurso._extension, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
        sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 3, recurso.contenido.bytes, Int32(recurso.contenido.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

        if sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE {
            let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
            print("Error al ejecutar insert:", errorMessage)
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
            return false;
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
        return true
    } else {
        let errorMessage = String.init(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
        print("Error al preparar sentencia:", errorMessage)
        return false
    }
}
```

And I am always getting the same error:

`Error al ejecutar insert:` **datatype mismatch**

I am sure the database connection and the image are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter numbering starts at 1, not 0.  You're thus trying to bind a string to the integer primary key column, which only works if the string contents can losslessly be converted to an integer.

Comment: It doesn't help that retrieving values from result rows is 0 based. Easy to get the two confused.

Answer (score 0):

A big pointing point here to whoever get into this situation is that the counter is according to the question marks "?" and starting from 1 (1 based) , so if you have this for example:

"INSERT INTO recurso(idRecurso, recurso, extension, contenido) VALUES(1234, 'hello', 'world', ?)";

inserting the blob here will require index 1, so this line will look like that:

sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, recurso.contenido.bytes, Int32(recurso.contenido.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)

failing to do it this way will result in error code SQLITE_RANGE (error code 25)